# Android MediaPlayer SSL Certificate Pinning

Tags: android, ssl, pinning

There are many descriptions of using SSL Certificate pinning for making HTTP requests on Android - which is a good thing.

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this when loading and playing an HLS stream via a VideoView/MediaPlayer?  With these we don't make the connections ourself - this is done by the system.  I want some way of being able to only trust my own certificates.